# Injection of a field from a ScriptableObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

I have a ScriptableObjectInstaller

```c#
public class Settings : ScriptableObjectInstaller<Settings>
{
    [Header("Gravity settings")] public GravityHandler.Settings GravitySettings;
    [Header("Movement settings")] public MovementHandler.Settings MovementSettings;

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInstance(GravitySettings);
        Container.BindInstance(MovementSettings);
    }
}
```

and a class

```c#
public class GravityHandler : IGravityHandler
{
    private readonly Settings _settings;
    private readonly BoxCollider2D _groundBox2D;

    public GravityHandler(BoxCollider2D groundBox2D, Settings settings)
    {
        _groundBox2D = groundBox2D;
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public bool IsGrounded()
    {
        if (_groundBox2D.OverlapCollider(_settings.ContactFilter2D, null) > 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Settings
    {
        public ContactFilter2D ContactFilter2D;
        public Vector3 GravityForce=new Vector2(0, -9.8f);
    }
}
```

All I want is to be able to change Settings.GravitySettings, and then inject its value into GravityHandler._settings, so i can use the settings inside GravityHandler.
But when I validate my scene it shows me an error:

> ZenjectException: Unable to resolve type 'GravityHandler+Settings' while building object with type 'GravityHandler'. 
>   Object graph:
>   Player
>   MovementHandler
>   GravityHandler

What do I do wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just forgot to put the scriptable object into SceneContext. I also had to change its name to match the name of the class.